# How to convert this linqTOsql query to lambda

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

This is more of a brain teaser for me as the linqTOsql query is fulfilling the need. I am just curious as to how a query like this could be converted to lambda's or if that's even possible.

I had originally tried to accomplish this with lambdas, but the only way I could figure out how to accomplish the joins so I could order results correctly was to use the query syntax:

```
        var entries = from e2c in entry2CatsTable
                      join sEntries in streamEntryTable
                      on e2c.streamEntryID equals sEntries.seID
                      orderby sEntries.seDateCreated descending
                      orderby e2c.e2cOrder
                      where e2c.catID == catID
                      select sEntries;
```

I had played around with this using lambdas and this is how far i got:

```
        IQueryable<Entry2Cats> e2c = entry2CatsTable
                                        .Where(x => x.catID == catID)
                                        .OrderBy(x => x.e2cOrder);
        IQueryable<StreamEntry> entries = e2c.SelectMany(x => x.StreamEntry);
```

These lambdas return the correct results but I couldn't order them correctly because I needed to order based on fields in the `Entry2Cats` table and the `StreamEntry` table. Because that was a many to many a statement like this doesn't work:

```
// doesn't work because it doesn't know which x.Entry2Cats.e2cOrder to use
entries.OrderByDescending(x => x.seDateCreated).OrderBy(x => x.Entry2Cats.e2cOrder);
```

Any thoughts?

#### Note:

Also, results need to be returned as `IQueryable` because the controller adds pagination functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var entries = entry2CatsTable
                .Join(streamEntryTable, e2c => e2c.streamEntryID, sEntries => sEntries.seID, (e2c, sEntries) => new { e2c, sEntries })
                .Where(item => item.e2c.catID == catID)
                .OrderByDescending(item => item.sEntries.seDateCreated)
                .ThenBy(item => item.e2c.e2cOrder)
                .Select(item => item.sEntries);
```

Comment: Note: If you download LINQPad, you can load configure it to use your linq-to-sql connection and objects and plug your query expression syntax in. You will be able to run it and see the lambda version, generated SQL, IL, and results (as applicable).

Comment: Wow. Usually I prefer the lambda code... but in the case I think the query is easier to read lol. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: That `.Join()` syntax is a bit of a mind melter. But I plugged it in and it is correct.